# :not fire any event in updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

i have a website with `.Net2` . I Changed it built target to `.Net4.5` and changed it pool to `.net 4` from `IIS`. but any event in `updatepanel` not firing(such as `butun_click` or `dropdown_Changed` and ...) all of them work correctly on .net 2.
any idea?

**Edit:
i delete:**

```
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>

  <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>

            <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>

  <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
```

from web.config becuase duplicated error.

Comment: Did you change any of the definitions in the web.config? .Net 2.0 and 3.5 have configuration settings for the system.web.extensions pieces but .Net 4.x doesn't require them.

Comment: @Mark Fitzpatrick see my edit please.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need any of the system.web.extensions references in the web.config when using the .Net 4.X framework. Technically, Ajax and the Web.Extensions namespace was baked into the 3.5 release, but at the same time it was released as a downloadable dll for 2.0. To make it easier, and since 3.5 is built on top of 2.0, MS required this in the web.config. With 4.x it's already all setup and baked into 4.x so any of the system.web.extensions pieces in the web.config are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution.
the problem was with this line:

```
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequestHandler);
    function InitializeRequestHandler(sender, eventArgs) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelID.indexOf('folCountTimer') != -1) {
            return;
        }
        $("#updateProgresJQuery").slideDown(300);
    }
```

i delete it and every thing work correctly.